# Watir fails to interact with elements and reports that they are disabled

Tags: watir

Whilst automating a collection of integration tests for various OAUTH providers, I found that watir does not seem to work with the Fitbit auth page, and always reports that the text_fields are disabled, no matter what I do.

This may be a bug in watir, or it may be something peculiar to the the Fitbit page (broken HTML or deliberate anti-scripting code).

The fitbit page is located at https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize/

watir can detect the email text_field exists:
`browser.wait_until{ browser.text_field( name: 'email' ).exists? }`

but any attempt to interact with it reports an error that it is disabled:
`browser.text_field( name: 'email' ).wait_until_present`

I've tried tabbing through all the fields on the page to see if this enables it, and I've tried using `browser.driver.action.move_to` to click on the element, but nothing seems to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for providing not only the code you are working with, but also a link to the page.  This makes it far easier for us to debug what's going on and provide you with a working answer.

Comment: My pleasure: anything to make the process easier for all! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there are 3 text fields with the name "email". If you get a collection of the text fields, you can see that only some of them are visible:

```
browser.text_fields(name: 'email').map(&:visible?)
#=> [false, true, false]
```

Watir interacts with the first match, which in this case is one of the hidden fields. You actually want the second field - ie the visible one.

You can use the `:visible` flag to tell Watir to find the first visible one:

```
browser.text_field(name: 'email', visible: true).set('value')
```

Comment: Damn, I thought I'd checked for that too. ;)

Thanks for the answer, all works perfectly now.